# Error when using tinyMCE in my wordpress settings page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I tried using tinyMCE directly from the package included with:

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

And then I just set this in my jQuery file:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
});
```

Now, for some reason that I can't understand, all my textareas are hidden (visibility:hidden) and nothing else is showing up. I am modifying the DOM in this file with jQuery but I tried to insert a non-modified textarea and still nothing shows up. Is there something with Wordpress that makes this error? I am writing this in the functions.php-file.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you should simply use wp_editor() php function

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

Comment: It says in the documentation that you can't modify the DOM with wp_editor(). I would like to add some textareas with jQuery and still have the tinymce functionality on each.